# how to rename multiple files in a folder with a specific format? perl syntax explanation

Tags: perl

I asked a similar question previously, but need help to understand the Perl commands that achieve the renaming process. I have many files in a folder with format '{galaxyID}-psf-calexp-pdr2_wide-HSC-I-{#}-{#}-{#}.fits'. Here are some examples:

```
7-psf-calexp-pdr2_wide-HSC-I-9608-7,2-205.41092-0.41487.fits
50-psf-calexp-pdr2_wide-HSC-I-9332-6,8-156.64674--0.03277.fits
124-psf-calexp-pdr2_wide-HSC-I-9323-4,3-143.73514--0.84442.fits
```

I want to rename all .fits files in the directory to match the following format:

```
7-HSC-I-psf.fits
50-HSC-I-psf.fits
124-HSC-I-psf.fits
```

namely, I want to remove "psf-calexp-pdr2_wide", all of the numbers after "HSC-I", and add "-psf" to the end of each file after HSC-I.  I have tried the following command:

```
rename -n -e 's/-/-\d+-calexp-/-\d+pdr2_wide; /-/-//' *.fits
```

which gave me the error message: Argument list too long. You can probably tell I don't understand the Perl syntax. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `Argument list too long` doesn't come from `perl`; it comes from the shell because you have so many files that `*.fits` expanded to something too long.

To fix this, use

```sh
# GNU
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.fits' -exec rename ... {} +
```

```sh
# Non-GNU
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.fits' -print0 | xargs -0 rename ...
```

---

But your Perl code is also incorrect. All you need is

```perl
s/^(\d+).*/$1-HSC-I-psf.fits/
```

which can also be written as

```perl
s/^\d+\K.*/-HSC-I-psf.fits/
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I tried to fix the shell error by using the command you gave me (non-GNU), but it gave me the error "Unimplemented at (eval 2) line 1." Any idea why?

Comment: You're not suppose to literally use `...`...